# How to determine how many times midnight is crossed during an Interval

Tags: jodatime

I have a joda-time [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) that stretches across multiple days. What's the best way to calculate the number of times it crosses midnight?

The Interval might or might not start at midnight on its start date, and might be less than a day long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I assume an interval which is half open meaning including start but excluding end. First I use the type `LocalDate` in order to exclude wall time effects on the date difference.

```
public int getCountOfMidnights(Interval interval) {
  LocalDate start = interval.getStart().toLocalDate();
  LocalDate end = interval.getEnd().toLocalDate();
  int countOfMidnights = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();

  if (interval.getStart().toLocalTime().equals(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)) {
    countOfMidnights++;
  }

  return countOfMidnights;
}
```

**UPDATE because of OPs own answer:**

I have tested his code especially for the timezone "America/Sao_Paulo" which introducted summertime on 2013-10-20 at midnight jumping to T01:00 instead.

Output using the solution of @GabrielBauman yields:

```
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo");
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 10, 20, 5, 0, tz);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 10, 21, 0, 0, tz);
    Interval interval = new Interval(start.withTimeAtStartOfDay(), end);
    System.out.println(getCountOfMidnights(interval)); // 0!!!
```

With my solution the correct result is 1. There is also another problem with not taking in account the condition if an interval starts at midnight (OP has to consider if this shall be counted, too. In my opinion, yes, see also my comment below).

**Conclusion:** We have basically a date-only scenario when counting midnights.

Therefore it is wise to avoid temporal types (if possible) which include the timezone internally (like Joda-`DateTime` or JDK-GregorianCalendar or `ZonedDateTime` in new JSR-310) because here the time arithmetic is not sooo clear (it is sensible for wall time comparisons, too). That is the main reason why I used local types like `LocalDate`. And it is also one of several reasons why I abandon such mixed types in my own library (another reason is for example the missing option for direct storage in databases). These all-purpose types with date, time and timezone together are far less useful than most users believe. It is in most cases better to use local types and use global types mainly for timezone-aware conversion purposes.

Comment: Thanks for this. Care to critique the other answer?

Comment: @GabrielBauman Maybe you prefer your solution as better because it is a one-liner. But consider the interval `new Interval(0, 86402000, DateTimeZone.UTC)` which will produce 2 days in my solution, but 1 day in your solution. So both answers are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for examining this further! Some really good information here. I'll mark your answer as correct; really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```java
public int getCountOfMidnights(Interval i) {
    return Days.daysIn(i.withStart(i.getStart().withTimeAtStartOfDay())).getDays();
}
```

Essentially, I adjust the interval's start time to the time at start of day (usually midnight), then count the number of full days contained in the adjusted interval.

Not sure if this is better or worse than the other answer pending some testing, so I'll leave it here in case people have comments.